VictoriaMetrics MetricsQL/PromQL : show series average grouped by the hour of the day
I am trying to represent data of a series aggregated by the hour of the day. Specifically, I want the average and standard deviation over a period (preceding weeks) at the same hour of the day as the data. In MySQL, I would accomplish this with such a query :
Table named "hitcount" (ts timestamp, hits float)
 with e1 as (
  select
    avg(hits) a,
    std(hits) s,
    hour(ts) h
  from
    hitcount
  where
     unix_timestamp(ts) >= unix_timestamp(now())-28*86400
  group by
    h
)
select
  unix_timestamp(t1.ts) time_sec,
  t1.hits hits,
  e1.a average,
  e1.s stddev
from
  hitcount as t1
  join e1 on hour(t1.ts) = e1.h;

So this would provide rows a "time_sec, hits, average, stddev"  with "average" and "stddev" being the hourly average at the same hour of the day as the "time_sec" of the value "hits" on the preceding 28 days.
Is there any way do this with MetricsQL/PromQL ?
I have Googled, searched the docs of VictoriaMetrics and asked ChatGPT before, to no avail.

Try the following MetricsQL query:
aggr_over_time(("avg_over_time","stddev_over_time","last_over_time"), hitcount[1h])

This query uses aggr_over_time function for calculating multiple aggregate functions over the hitcount raw samples over the last hour.
You can also perform multiple queries for different functions in a single query by using union and alias functions:
union(
  alias(avg_over_time(hitcount[1h]), "avg"),
  alias(stddev_over_time(hitcount[1h]), "stddev"),
  alias(last_over_time(hitcount[1h]), "last"),
)

See also rollup_candlestick function, which is very convenient for financial calculations such as OHLC.
If you want calculating per-hour values for the queries above for the last 28 days, you need to pass this query to /api/v1/query_range together with step=1h and start=-28d query args.
